# Efficiently count individual hours in date ranges

Tags: javascript, loops, date, time

I would like to calculate an hourly count (or another interval) of elements that have start and end times.

Suppose, it's an hourly interval with the following sample set:

```
const sampleSet = [
  {
    start_date: "2020-06-01",
    end_date: "2020-06-01",
    start_time: "08:00",
    end_time: "12:00"
  },
  {
    start_date: "2020-06-01",
    end_date: "2020-06-01",
    start_time: "10:00",
    end_time: "13:00"
  }
];
```

The end result would look something like this:

```
const result = [
 {
   "2020-06-01 00:00": 0,
   ...
   "2020-06-01 07:00": 0,
   "2020-06-01 08:00": 1,
   "2020-06-01 09:00": 1,
   "2020-06-01 10:00": 2,
   "2020-06-01 11:00": 2,
   "2020-06-01 12:00": 2,
   "2020-06-01 13:00": 1,
   "2020-06-01 14:00": 0,
   ...
 }
]
```

I'm aware that I could loop through every hour and count all elements that are within the timeslot, but this could end in a lot of loops, especially when it's for a longer timeframe.

I think it would be better if I'd loop through the elements instead and assign them to the time slots. For example, push array slots.

I would convert them to a moment object first for easier modification:

```
const DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm";

const formattedElements = sampleSet.map(element => ({
  start: moment(element.start_date + " " + element.start_time, DATE_TIME_FORMAT),
  end: moment(element.end_date + " " + element.end_time, DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
}));
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed now.

Would appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looping over the time ranges. As each new date is encountered, check if there are slots for it and if not, create them. Then add counts for the related range.

Since you're only dealing with one date format, simple parse and format functions are all that are needed, e.g.

```js
// Parse timestamp in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm
function parse(s) {
  let [Y, M, D, H, m] = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Y, M-1, D, H||0, m||0);
}

// Format date as YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm
function format(d) {
  let z = n => (n<10? '0':'') + n;
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' +
    z(d.getDate()) + ' ' + z(d.getHours()) + ':' + z(d.getMinutes());
}

// Add slots given start date s, end date e, 
// interval i in minutes to object o
function addSlots(s, e, i, o) {
  // Copy start and set to start of day
  let d = new Date(s);
  d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  // Store the end date
  let t = e.getDate();
  // Add slots from start to end
  while (d.getDate() <= t) {
    o[format(d)] = 0;
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + i);
  }
}

// Loop over elements, adding slots and counts for each element
// for interval i
function genSlotCounts(data, i) {
  let slots = {};

  data.forEach(obj => {
    // Setup for loop
    let start = parse(obj.start_date + ' ' + obj.start_time);
    let end   =  parse(obj.end_date + ' ' + obj.end_time);
    // Check for slots, add if missing
    if (!slots.hasOwnProperty(format(start))) {
      addSlots(start, end, i, slots);
    }
    // Loop over the range, incrementing on each loop, adding 1 to slot
    while (start <= end) {
      // Update slots
      slots[format(start)] += 1;
      start.setMinutes(start.getMinutes() + i);
    }
  });
  return slots;
}

let data = [
  {
    start_date: "2020-06-01",
    end_date: "2020-06-03",
    start_time: "08:00",
    end_time: "12:00"
  },
  {
    start_date: "2020-06-01",
    end_date: "2020-06-01",
    start_time: "10:00",
    end_time: "13:00"
  },
  {
    start_date: "2020-06-02",
    end_date: "2020-06-02",
    start_time: "06:00",
    end_time: "18:00"
  },
  {
    start_date: "2020-06-02",
    end_date: "2020-06-02",
    start_time: "09:00",
    end_time: "13:00"
  },
  {
    start_date: "2020-06-02",
    end_date: "2020-06-02",
    start_time: "12:00",
    end_time: "16:00"
  }
];

let slots = genSlotCounts(data, 60);
console.log(slots);
```

There are still issues with the above, such as the potential to overwrite existing slots, how to deal with midnight at the end of the day, what happens if the interval isn't an integer divisor of 24 hours, etc. but it should get you going.